# Python failing to import module from script

Tags: python, import, python-import

If I start python and input `import tables` it works fine but when I run `python m_BlackrockLib.py` (which has `import os, struct, tables, pickle, re, shutil` as it's first line) I get the error `ImportError: No module named tables`. I can see that tables is present in `/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-package` so I'm not sure what is causing this error. Can anyone see the issue?

Comment: Could be that you have multiple pythons installed and that one of them doesn't have the module. The ``python m_BlackrockLib.py`` uses whatever python is linked to your ``python`` command. Open a python console by just typing ``python`` and see if it fails too.

Comment: `which python` returns `/usr/local/anaconda/bin/python` which, I believe, is what it should be

Comment: Are you running *exactly* the same `python` command in both cases?  For example, are you developing your script in a virtualenv or something of that nature?  Virtualenv usually skips the site-packages.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `import conda` to the script above the other imports because I have `tables` installed in anaconda